# Numpy - extract array2d columns based on array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a multidimensional numpy array with shape (40, 926). 
I have also a numpy array shape (126) with random indexes that represens the valid columns.

Now, I would like to do is filter my multidimensional array based on this mask of indexes: all columns different of this indexes must be removed resulting shape (40,126)

So, something like:

```
data = np.array([[]])
sel = np.asarray(idx.split(',')) 
print sel.shape #(126) array 404,410,500...1300
print X.shape #(40,926) 
for x in wave: #(926) array 400,401,402...1325
    for y in sel:
        if float(x) == float(y):
            index = np.where(wave == x)[0][0]
            arr =  X[:,index]
            data = np.append(data, arr, axis=1)
print data.shape #must be (40,126)
return data
```

Error occurring: return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If wave and sel arrays are already sorted, you can get indexes of wave where
wave == sel and use them to select rows from the matrix

```
idx = wave.searchsorted(sel)
data = X[:, idx]
```

Comment: I want to select not delete

Comment: It's more easier

Comment: great... but I need sel indexes related with wave as the example above